# SSL certificate in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, ssl

An error window saying that the site which the app's trying to access isn't compatible with the ssl certificate,pop up each time an app access the internet:

[image]

How to fix that ?

Comment: Which application?

Comment: each one which access the internet, maybe it's a bug already noticed?

Comment: Could be some missing CA: have you tried updating `ca-certificates`?

Comment: Please stop making useless edits to bump your question.

Comment: @SYN: Yes i tried , still happening.